# Calculating columns is SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint

I have created some list in SharePoint with columns (name, id_work_acc, count_id_work_acc, schedule_time, working_hours_required, efficiency) and in column count_id_work_acc i want to return number of id-s of work acc (for example if I have in 3 rows id_work_acc = 4, in count_id_work_acc will be shown 3). Next, in column "efficiency" I want to use this formula (efficiency = ([schedule_time] - [working_hours_required]) / [count_id_work_acc]). How can I implement this, please help?

I tried this:

`=IF(ISNUMBER([schedule_time]) && ISNUMBER([working_hours_required]), ([schedule_time] - [working_hours_required]) / COUNT(count_id_work_acc),  "")`

but it doesn't work. And I thought if this problem can be solved by using COUNTIF instead of using COUNT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to achieve your requirements (to calculate value for `count_id_work_acc` column) using SharePoint calculated column formula because formula cannot read column values from another rows/list items.

SharePoint calculated column formula can read column values from same row/list item only:

[image]

---

If you want to update the column values immediately on item creation/upated, you can try customizing the SharePoint list forms using Power Apps, calculate the column values using power apps formulas while creating/editing list item.

**Documentation**: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

**OR** you can use the Power automate flow to do the calculation and update the column values in the list (flow can be run immediately after item creation/update or based on schedule like once in a day or based on different timings in a day as per your requirements).